Why oh why does 7-zip insists on compressing the Recycle bin and found.000 root folders?
Just go to the root of a drive that has these folders, and do for instance:
E:
cd\
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a E:\elec\teste11.7z *.*

And you'll see it analyzing $RECYCLE.BIN and it's subfolders. The same happens if you have the folder found.000. What the hell is this? What makes it think I want to compress that?
Using the non-recursive switch **-r-** does absolutely nothing, and by the way, no other folders present in the root drive are being compressed, only the Recycle and found.000, so it's not like I'm telling him to recurse the whole drive.
I'm also not using the recurse particular folders switch -ir!.
I only want to compress all the files (and only the files) present in the root drive.
Does anyone knows why 7zip is compressing these 2, and only these 2 folders?  I can't be the only one that noticed this, but my internet searches didn't return anything. Since no other folder is compressed, hidden or not, I'm guessing this is a bug from 7zip that must have these 2 folders hardcoded for something, and somehow it's compressing them.
Any help will be appreciated.
Note:  I know I can just exclude those folders with -x!E:\$RECYCLE.BIN -x!E:\found.000, but I shouldn't have to add this to bypass buggy programming, or to have to put his exceptions on my other batch files.

What version of Windows?

Windows 10, with the latest updates.


What makes it think I want to compress that?

You specified the wildcard pattern *.*, which matches the names FOUND.000 and $RECYCLE.BIN, so you explicitly told 7z to compress those two items by name.
Since it is meaningless to compress a directory itself, the only sensible interpretation 7z can have of receiving a directory name through command line is to recurse at least one level deep into that directory regardless of other options.
So if you don't want 7z to compress some of the items that your wildcard pattern matches, you will need to exclude them individually using -x or specify a pattern that doesn't match such names.

Thanks for the answer. You mean he will compress any folder with a dot in the name? Then how can I compress just the files, and not any folder? I tried "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a E:\elec\teste11.7z *  (changed the * . * to just an *), but it compressed every folder. And this doesn't happen just at root level, but within any folder.

Wanting to compress just files with subfolders laying around seems to be a pretty basic and common need, why does 7zip does this? Specially since I was able to do this in the past, so 7zip must have had some "update" that changed things for the worst, and I haven't noticed it maybe because I haven't updated it for a long time until recently.
I would upvote the answer, but I don't seem to have enough "reputation" lol.
But someone downvoted my question... gee, thanks...

Well, I finally found the solution. Since no one here appears to know, I'll post the solution here:
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a  -x!*\  E:\elec\teste11.7z *
, with the -x!*\ being the important bit to NOT compress subfolders, something I thought was pretty trivial and basic.
Sorry but having to waste hours to find such a basic thing that is promised by a switch "but not really", is unacceptable.
The 1st problem with 7zip is that not only recursiveness is turned on by default, rendering -r useless except for some obscure exceptions, which shouldn't be the main focus of a basic function like recursive, but we can't turn it off with switches — forget about -r-, it's as useless as -r, they just work if I provide a folder which stores what I want to compress, and it won't recurse only for specific filetypes or something. I forgot, but it's something like this.
Worse even, more often than not it'll do a scan of the entire folder searching for things, when I 'told' it not to recurse. Since I'm working at the root level, it will scan the entire drive, even the recycle bin with it's tens of thousands of files. Brilliant.
-r is a main, core function, it's supposed to affect the whole compression, instead of being relegated to secondary or tertiary behaviour.
I don't now what's the author idea, but this is just being obtuse, nothing else. It adds nothing, it doesn't improve anything, just being different for the sake of being different, but yet adopting the same switches other similar programs use and with the same descriptions, which will only mislead users. Sorry but this is dumb beyond belief, and I'm being nice here (yes, it's now a rant).
I can't trust this program to compress my stuff the way I want it, fearing that the few things that still work now will break after another future F-up -I mean- "update", so, back to Winrar I guess, at least it won't try to fix what isn't broken. A pity, 7zip compressed really well.
And for the guy who was complaining (comment now deleted) that I was being "picky" (lol) and I should use the GUI, I'm making a backup script, which will be executed after another program finishes, meaning automation, meaning no I won't be using the GUI each time the program does it job.
Good luck with this thing, who knows, one of this days the 'a' switch will add files, but not really, only in certain specific situations and combinations, because "reasons".


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
